# Can't deserialize from json to list of custom objects

Tags: flutter, dart

Android Studio 4

In `assets/json/gaz_stations_list.json`

```
[
    {
        "Latitude": "47.0406",
        "Phone": " +(123) 11111"
    },
    {
        "Latitude": "47.0425",
        "Phone": " +(111) 22222"
    }
]
```

My class:

```
import 'dart:ffi';

class GazStation {
  Double latitude;
  String phone;

  GazStation(this.latitude, this.phone);

  GazStation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : latitude = json['latitude'],
        phone = json['phone'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
        'latitude': latitude,
        'phone': phone,
      };

}
```

Service class:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sample/model/GazStation.dart';

class GazStationService {

     Future<List<dynamic>> getGazStationList() async {
        return await rootBundle.loadString("assets/json/gaz_stations_list.json")
            .then((jsonStr) => jsonDecode(jsonStr));
      }
    
    }
```

And usage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
Widget _createMapNearestGazStationContianerLeft() {
    _logger.d("_createMapNearestGazStationContianerLeft:");
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: GazStationService().getGazStationList(),
        builder: (context, projectSnap) {
          if (projectSnap.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              projectSnap.hasData != null) {
            List<GazStation> gazStationList = projectSnap.data;
```

but `gazStationList` is **null**

Comment: Your qusetion tags are wrong. This is a flutter and dart only question, nothing in this code is Android related.

Comment: Could you print `jsonStr` in `getGazStationList` and share the output? Also it's not necessary to `await` a `.then` here. You can just `return` `.then` without `await`.

Comment: Its always good to check for errors like `projectSnap.hasError` before going ahead with processing.  Its possible that future completed with an error so `projectSnap.hasData != null` condition will be true but there would be an error instead of the expected data.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sample/model/GazStation.dart';

class GazStationService {
  Future<List<dynamic>> getGazStationList() async {
    var jsonStr =
        await rootBundle.loadString("assets/json/gaz_stations_list.json");
    var list = json.decode(jsonStr) as List;
    // iterate over the list and map each object in list to GazStation by calling GazStation.fromJson
    List<GazStation> gazStationList = list.map((i) => GazStation.fromJson(i)).toList();
    return gazStationList;
  }
}
```

and now

```
  Widget _createMapNearestGazStationContianerLeft() {
    _logger.d("_createMapNearestGazStationContianerLeft:");
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: GazStationService().getGazStationList(),
        builder: (context, projectSnap) {
          if (projectSnap.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              projectSnap.hasData != null) {
            List<GazStation> gazStationList = projectSnap.data;
```

the `gazStationList` content list fill with correct data.

Answer (score -1):

probably `projectSnap.data` is null because :

1- `projectSnap.hasData` is never null, it's either true or false.

2- `projectSnap.data` is a string, it's not a list. If you want it to be a deserliazed JSON list, you need to first convert it to JSON, then use a `List.of()`.

Comment: Your second statement is incorrect. `projectSnap.data` contains an equivalent of  `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`. The OP is still doing an incorrect assignment, but that's not what you're claiming.